# How to generate msbuild bootstrapper to install .net 4.0 prerequisite from web

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, wix, wix3.8

I have spent several days looking for a solution to this issue to without any real result. I have a WiX 3.8 project to install an Excel Add-In. The project creates an MSI. I need to bootstrap into this project the ability to check if the .net framework 4.0 client is installed and if not, to install it from the web.

There are 2 possible solutions to this problem that I have found:

1. Create a WiX bootstrap project.
2. Use the MSBuild bootstrapper that comes with Visual Studio 2012.
3. Run a Post-build event command line

If I go with item 1, then there is no way to generate an MSI, which is a requirement.
I would like to do item 2 or 3, but cannot find an example that will create the necessary bootstrap executable for the download of the pre-requisite.

Can anyone assist me?

**Edit 1**
I have attempted to do item 1 as shown below.  I am able to display the UI from my MSI using the DisplayInternalUI="yes" flag and to style the burn UI using themes and the WixBalExtensionExt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
  xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Product Name" 
      Version="1.0.0.0" 
      Manufacturer="Company Name" 
      IconSourceFile="..\path\to\Icon.ico"
      DisableModify="yes"
      UpgradeCode="[guid]">
     <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
         <Payload SourceFile="Resource\Image1.png"/>
         <Payload SourceFile="Resource\Image2.png"/>
         <bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseUrl="" />
     </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
     <WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeXml" Value="Resource\AddInTheme.xml" />
     <WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeWxl" Value="Resource\AddInTheme.wxl" />
     <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id ="NetFx40ClientWeb"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="MyPackage" 
              SourceFile="..\MyPackage\bin\$(var.Configuration)\MyPackage.msi"
              Vital="yes"
              DisplayInternalUI="yes"
              />
    </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

If there is a way to create a bootstrapper application as an MSI, please let me know.

Otherwise, please confirm if I use the built in bootstrapper to visual studio if I need to use a condition in the WiX script to install it. How does this work?

**Edit 2**
Since the WiX bootstrapper only produces an EXE, it does not meet my requirements.  Is there an actual example of how to bootstrap the .net download (not the redistributable) to the WiX project? There are many examples for the redistributable but none for the download.

Comment: Did you try looking at the [WiX Burn tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html)?

Comment: Yes. The problem that I have is that the burn projects only support an output of exe and my requirement is to create an MSI.  Essentially, one MSI will include another. I have no idea why this limitation exists as I would otherwise to this.

Comment: I suggest you re-validate your requirements, perhaps by comparing with installers for well known products (.NET Framework, WiX itself, Visual Studio, ...). Also, note that when you create a WiX Bootstrapper it must produce an EXE but you can leave your MSI "loose" so you will in fact be delivering an MSI that anyone can see. Inside the MSI you should use an InstallCondition to enforce the requirement that prerequisites be installed first, with an error message suggesting that running "setup.exe" would be the easiest way to do that.

Comment: My requirements are valid - i.e. no EXE, though I will recheck with my architect. I have spent a long time vetting WiX and have been using it for a year before getting the additional requirement that the prerequisite needs to be installed before running the rest of the MSI. Is there any way to suppress the dialog in the WiX bootstrapper project since the MSI has the dialog I want to show? The example above does show the MSI dialog, but suppression of the bootstrapper dialog does not work.